# Assigning a variable name as an object property while using Array.prototype.map

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I'm iterating through an array of arrays using `.map()` in an attempt to assign the inner arrays to an object as a `key:value` pair. It is not successful. Can this even work? Do I need to break it out into more steps/functions/variables?

I've tried every syntax I can think of for the element in the assignment of the property.

I also tried using `arr.map(function() {})` syntax with all of these, and there was no difference.

```js
const smallArr = [1, 23, 25, 46, 52, 789, 64];

const thisArr = [5, 4, 65, 24, 35];

const thatArr = [{key: 1, anotherKey: 2}];

let parentObj = {};

const bigArr = [smallArr, thisArr, thatArr];

const newSomething = bigArr.map(arr => parentObj["arr"] = arr);

// parentObj returns: { arr: [ { key: 1, anotherKey: 2 } ] }
```

I understand both of these. It's assigning the string of my element
every iteration and overwriting the value so that the final object is
one key:value pair with value being the last inner array in the outer
array.

```js
const newSomething = bigArr.map(arr => parentObj.arr = arr);
  //returns { arr: [ { key: 1, anotherKey: 2 } ] }

const newSomething = bigArr.map(arr => parentObj['arr'] = arr);
  //returns { arr: [ { key: 1, anotherKey: 2 } ] }
```

This one I don't understand what's going on in the last pair.

```js
const newSomething = bigArr.map(arr => parentObj[`${arr}`] = arr);
  // returns { 
        '1,23,25,46,52,789,64': [ 1, 23, 25, 46, 52, 789, 64 ], 
        '5,4,65,24,35': [ 5, 4, 65, 24, 35 ], 
        '[object Object]': [ { key: 1, anotherKey: 2 } ], 
         arr: [ { key: 1, anotherKey: 2 } ] 
        }
```

This one I don't understand at all.

```js
const newSomething = bigArr.map(arr => parentObj["`${arr}`"] = arr);
  // returns { 
        '`${arr}`': [ { key: 1, anotherKey: 2 } ], 
         arr: [ { key: 1, anotherKey: 2 } ] 
         }
```

I'm trying to get to:

```js
parentObj = {
    smallArr: [1, 23, 25, 46, 52, 789, 64],
    thisArr: [5, 4, 65, 24, 35],
    thatArr: [{key: 1, anotherKey: 2}],
}
```

Comment: Your array contains just arrays - they are not named `smallArr`, `thisArr` or `thatArr` any more. If `bigArr` is all you have, then you will need to spell out the property names explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just explicitly assign each variable:

```js
const smallArr = [1, 23, 25, 46, 52, 789, 64];
const thisArr = [5, 4, 65, 24, 35];
const thatArr = [{key: 1, anotherKey: 2}];
let parentObj = { smallArr, thisArr, thatArr };

console.log(parentObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

The above is shorthand for:

```js
const smallArr = [1, 23, 25, 46, 52, 789, 64];
const thisArr = [5, 4, 65, 24, 35];
const thatArr = [{key: 1, anotherKey: 2}];
let parentObj = { smallArr: smallArr, thisArr: thisArr, thatArr: thatArr };

console.log(parentObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: I did not mean to, I tried to check both answers because they were the same and I guess it downvoted yours when I checked the second

Comment: It's OK - you can accept the other one @DoubleBridges. Just un-accept mine first.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use object literal [**shorthand property**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions)

```js
let smallArr = [1, 23, 25, 46, 52, 789, 64];
let thisArr =  [5, 4, 65, 24, 35];
let thatArr = [{key: 1, anotherKey: 2}];
let parentObj = { smallArr, thisArr, thatArr,}

console.log(parentObj)
```